# call wcf function, and always get "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" message

Tags: wcf-client

Hope somebody give me any idea how to handle this

I add one service reference and want to call one function like `GetAllObjects()` in C#, it should

```
DataServiceClient dataClientService = new DataServiceClient();
Object[] adlist = dataClientService.GetAllObjects(startdateTime, enddateTime);
```

the error is

> *Window received an HTTP error message: 403(Forbidden) from Detected
>   "localhost"*

Comment: Does it work on Chrome/Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Likely the URL your WCF service client is pointing at is incorrect. Try connecting to your service using the [WCF test client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx).

Comment: I just start to use WCF, and go through the 'WCF test Client'page, I didn't find WcfTestClient.exe in my directory

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE